# .NET Website Crashing

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, coldfusion

I work on a very large, high traffic ecommerce website. We're currently migrating our site from ColdFusion to .NET. We've recently run into an issue during this conversion that I was hoping for a little help with. Our current website is about 1/3 .net now and 2/3 ColdFusion.

One issue though, is that when we release our latest project, which is a project to convert the My Account section everything is fine for awhile, but anywhere between 3 to 24 hours the website just crashes. In order to get it back up, we need to restart IIS and sometimes ColdFusion. When I say crashes, I mean it just hangs, sits there and spins forever.

We have really good server monitoring, but when we look at the services memory nothing look unusual except for the number of connections to SQL. For some reason fairly quickly before the crash SQL shoots up in the number of connections, it goes from around 24 connections to around 100, just sits there and the site goes down until we restart services.

We currently use SQL Server 2005, Entity framework as our data access method and we're on IIS 7.5. Our web server is virtual but our database is physical.

We've had multiple people on our team go through all of the code in this new project to confirm that their were no connections that were being left open, as based on the connections issues that's sort of how is seems. We couldn't find any connections left open, not one.

This is an example of our current data access to entity:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get Products by their Primary Category ID.  Default Category ID is 0: Top Level Categories.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="languageCode">Two character language code of Categories being searched.  Defined in dbo.Languages, LanguageCode field.</param>
    /// <param name="primaryCategoryId">int - Primary Category ID</param>
    /// <returns>List&lt;Product%gt;</returns>
    public List<Products.Product> GetProducts(string languageCode, int primaryCategoryId = 0)
    {
        CatalogEntity context = null;
        EntityConnection conn = null;

        try
        {
            conn = this.GetConnection();
            context = new CatalogEntity(conn);

            List<I_Products> Products = context.GetProductsByPrimaryCatId(primaryCategoryId, languageCode).Distinct().ToList();
            return Products.Select(Product => new Products.Product(Product)).Distinct().ToList();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            string message = "Error occurred while calling GetProducts.";
            throw new Exception.CatalogDataException(message, CodeLibrary.Core.Helpers.ProcessHelper.GetProcessName(this), ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null && conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close();
            if (context != null) context.Dispose();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Again, this is just one example of one of our data access methods in C#. Don't see any issues with this do you? Again, we use this format across the board. We've confirmed this.

With the new .net project, we use .net membership provider. We use a CLR to encrypt users passwords with a hash so that we can use the same hash method in CF. Not sure if this is the issue but thought it was worth mentioning.

Any ideas?

Comment: The fact that the number of SQL connections spikes before crashes suggests a database problem.  Could it be a deadlock or timeout in SQL Server?

Comment: Probably figure out what each of these new SQL connections are doing (what queries are being run), that might shed some light on why they're being created.

Comment: We've run SQL profiler before and during one of these crashes and didn't see anything that looks out of the norm.

Comment: We ran SP_WHO2 to look at the active connections after the spike occured and most of the new connections were sleeping

Comment: You have more information on the GetProductsByPrimaryCatId method?

Comment: So again the code I provided is really just an example of my data access. The GetProductsByPrimaryCatId method is a call to the entity framework stored procedure called GetProductsByPrimaryCatId. I can't provide this as it's part of my EF model.

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of possibilities here. For example, when a call to SQL server fails to return data to CF, CF can hang onto the thread. It becomes a sort of "phantom thread." CF then creates new connections to the DB server and adds them to the connection pool - resulting in the many extra connections you are seeing. It's counted against the "simultaneous requests" setting in the CF admin. When there are enough of them "hanging" your requests queue and your server locks up even if it doesn't appear anything is going on. You can see this behavior by enabling metrics, by using the server monitor (if on the Enterprise version) or by using fusionreactor (an excellent and inexpensive 3rd party introspective monitor for your CF/Java server).

Of course that is *what* is happening. You have to find out *why* it's happening. Among the possibilities are:

- Networking - sometimes autosynch on ports to your switches can interupt connections and result in hanging "phantom" threads. See this post on [Hanging jrun and networking](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2006/6/2/hanging.threads.network.Config).
- Database Locking - this can produce issues like this and may be occuring even if you think you are not seeing it. It's sometimes tricky to catch. One particular locking issue that can be troublesome is the "[max degree of parallelism](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2011/11/18/cf.mssql.parallelism)" which can result in fairly idle looking DB connections that are nonetheless hanging.

You will probably need to get a bit more information on the CF side of things to know exactly what is going on here.

---

Follow up ... I'm providing some possibilities from the CF side even though your question was from the .NET side. I'm assuming that CF could be in play since restarting CF sometimes fixes the issue.